# Visual Studio Compile Selenium Code to exe

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, compilation

I've made a .NET programme in C# with Visual Studio 2019.
It uses Selenium with a chrome webdriver.
When I compile it and run the exe file on my computer it works, but doesn't on other computers.

I'm probably compiling it wrong.
(Other programs without selenium were compiled successfully)

How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't understand why I'm getting downvoted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that the chrome web browsers used on the other computers weren't up to date.